# Django 3.0: Running backgound infinite loop in app ready()

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to find a way to constantly poll a server every x seconds from the `ready()` function of Django, basically something which looks like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'

    def ready(self):
        import threading
        import time
        from django.conf import settings
        from api import utils

        def refresh_ndt_servers_list():
            while True:
                utils.refresh_servers_list()
                time.sleep(settings.WAIT_SECONDS_SERVER_POLL)

        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=refresh_ndt_servers_list)
        thread1.start()
```

I just want my `utils.refresh_servers_list()` to be executed when Django starts/is ready and re-execute that same method (which populates my DB) every `settings.WAIT_SECONDS_SERVER_POLL` seconds indefinitely. The problem with that is if I run `python manage.py migrate` the `ready()` function gets called and never finishes. I would like to avoid calling this function during migration.
Thanks!

Comment: As written, your `_poll` function creates a background task and exits immediately. However, the background task relies on the event loop to run to service it, and your event loop runs only until `_poll` completes, i.e. it stops immediately. If your application is not written around an event loop (and Django isn't), you will need to create a background thread to run the task. In that case you don't need asyncio at all, you can simply use `threading.Thread` to launch the thread, and give it a function that looks like your `start()` function, but isn't async.

Comment: I edited my question using threads so it's much easier, but now I still encounter some issues

Comment: Are you sure the `ready` function never finishes, or is it that the script itself hangs? If it's the latter, you just need to add `daemon=True` when creating the thread.

Answer (score 0):

`AppConfig.ready()` is to **"... perform initialization tasks ..."** and make your app ready to run / serve requests. Actual app working logic should be run *after* django app is initialized.

For launching task at regular intervals **`cron`** job can be used.

Or, setup a periodic [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) task with [celery beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Also, provided task seems to be performing updates in database (good for it to be ***atomic***). It may be critical for it to have only ***single running instance*** of it. One instance of cronjob or one celery task take care of that.

However, the next job may still run if previous one has not yet finished or just be launched manually for some reason - adding some ***locking logic*** into task to check that only one is running (or lock database table for the run) may be desired.

Comment: It's good solution for periodic tasks. But what approch should be used where true polling required (e.g. polling message queue  with blocking read)?